# How to remove rows based on blank column values VB

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I need to remove the second and third row from my datatable using linq. I am treating first column as my column names. How do i do it?

[image]

Comment: means if there is no column names, i need to remove it from my table. in my case 2 and 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer i was looking for :)

```
dtCoverage.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(row) row.Item("  ").ToString()=String.Empty).ToList().ForEach(Sub(r) dtCoverage.Rows.Remove(r))
```